# How do I store the geocoded output in my original dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

I have a dataframe [data] that contains an address field (loc_address).  I want to maintain that dataframe and add to it the geometry points from geopandas.

This code correctly geocodes the addresses and creates a new dataset with the cleaned address and the geometric points:

```
geocode(data['loc_address'], provider = 'bing', api_key = 'API', timeout=3)
```

but I just want the results to be stored in the original dataset [data]

I have tried :

```
data['address','geometry'] = geocode(data['loc_address'], provider = 'bing', api_key = 'API', timeout=3)
```

but I get an error stating wrong number or elements passed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need double brackets data[['address','geometry']]

Comment: That is embarrassingly simple.  Thanks for your help! It worked

Comment: Sure, glad it helped!